# Javascript Regex Match List

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Essentially my regex does not match with this list :

> 1. Bling Boy’s Raiment                                                            3.5M+         Low               BBR
> 2. The Ice Crown                                                                     2.5m           Great             IC
> 3. Darkheart                                                                             1.7M+         Average        DH
> 4. Rainbow Shaggy                                                                 1.3M+         Great             RS
> 5. Illumina                                                                                 1.1M+         Average        Ill
> 6. Masked Hood of the Doomspeaker                                     800K+        Average        N/A
> 7. Azurewrath, Lord of the Void                                                750K+        Good            LoTV
> 8. Sparkle Time Fedora                                                            700K+        Amazing       STF
> 9. ): Euro 180                                                                            700K+       Good             Euro
> 10. Golden Robloxian Music Video Award                                650K+        Low               GRMVA
> 11. ): Red Grind                                                                          600K+       Average         RG
> 12. Purple Sparkletime Fedora                                                   500K+       Amazing        PSTF

Here is the Regex :

```
/(\d+)(\.)((?: [a-z]+)+)\s+(\d+\w\+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/gi
```

is the regex I see where the problem is but I try adding \' to it and it will still not capture :

1. Bling Boy’s Raiment                                                            3.5M+         Low               BBR

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you want the capture to work exactly?

Comment: I want it to only capture:
Bling Boy’s Raiment,
3.5M,
Low. 
BBR

That is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it should work:

```
/(\d+)(\.)([a-z’ ]+)\s+([\d.]+\w\+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/gi
```

I changed `((?: [a-z]+)+)` to `([a-z’ ]+)` -- putting the space inside the character set obviates the non-capturing group. And I changed the later `\d+` to `[\d.]+` so it will recognize numbers like `3.5`.

[REGEXR Demo](http://regexr.com?35lcn)

Comment: How would I catch "(" and ")" as it in "): Red Grind 600K+ Average RG"

Comment: Add those characters to the `[a-z’ ]` class

Comment: Are there any characters that are _not_ allowed in that part of the string? Maybe you should just use `.+` to allow anything.

Comment: I solved it :
/(\d+)(\.)([a-z0-9’:)(, ]+)\s+([\d.]+\w\+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/gi

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `/\d+.+/` with line ending

Comment: The problem is with the name not the "1.", The name "Bling Boy’s Raiment" has a ' in it so it does not capture it.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern might do what you need:

```
(\d+\.)\s+(.+)\s+([\d\.]+\w\+)\s+(low|great|good|average|amazing)\s+([a-z]+)
```

http://regexr.com?35ld9